# Ономастика и этимология

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, ономастика

Является ли ономастика частью этимологии? И практический вопрос: какими метками помечать вопросы о происхождении фамилий?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сказать, что ономастика — «часть» (лучше — раздел) ономасиологии. Этимология — наука, изучающая происхождение слов. Эти две области знания могут пересекаться, они взаимосвязаны, но «частью» этимологии ономастику назвать нельзя.

[этимология](/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f), [ономастика](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0).

Answer (score 1):

Ономастика и этимология - разные науки, конечно. Одна изучает происхождение слов, другая - всё об именах собственных, в том числе и происхождение имени. Когда мы спрашиваем о происхождении фамилии - это этимологические аспекты ономастики. Вероятно, метки должны быть обе - сначала ономастика, потом этимология.